# Extracting proportional coverage of polygon from raster layer in R

Tags: r, polygon, raster, spatial

I am trying to extract the proportional coverage of approximately 700 buffers polygons from a RasterLayer in `R`.

My `rasterlayer` is from USDA CropScape for the entire state of MS and I have approximately 700 buffers that are 900 acres each.

Normally I would use the extract function in `R` doing:

```
ex <- extract(x=raster, y=polygons)
```

However, that just gives me a large list. I was wanted for more of a table formatted like this:

| BufferID | Landcover1 | Landcover2 | Lancover3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Buffer1 | 0.34 | 0.25 | 0.41 |

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is 'zonal statistics'. Searching that term leads to a few answers on stack, e.g., https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297852/calculating-statistics-per-area-for-categorical-raster-using-r

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172850/speeding-up-extraction-time-of-proportion-of-land-cover-types-in-buffer-from-ras

Comment: @Skaqqs so that works to get the proportions for each ID in the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, but it gets rid of the other columns in the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and leaves only columns with the porportions. I want to add the columns of proportions directly to my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and not delete what is already in the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. That way I have other data that is associated with each polygon and ID.

Comment: How about using `merge()` to combine your proportion calculations to your SPDF? If that's not clear, you could share some data and I could post some example code.